# Monitor based queue without capacity limit

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue, thread-safety

I have an assignment I'm trying to complete which involves finishing up an implementation of a thread safe Queue which is built using Java's built-in monitors/locks.

Within this assignment I have to finish the implementation of a version which has a capacity limit (which I have done so far) and another one which has no capacity limit and uses the first one as a basis (which is where I'm having trouble)

Anyway, the class with the capacity limit (MyMBQueue) which works fine:

```java
public class MyMBQueue<E> implements BQueue<E> {

  protected E[] array;
  protected int head;
  protected int size;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * @param initialCapacity Initial queue capacity.
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code capacity <= 0}
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public MyMBQueue(int initialCapacity) {
    if(initialCapacity <= 0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial capacity needs to be larger than 0");
    }

    this.head = 0;
    this.size = 0;
    this.array = (E[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized int capacity() {
    return array.length;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized int size() {
    return size;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void add(E elem) {
    while (size == array.length) {
      try {
        wait();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new UnexpectedException(e);
      }
    }

    array[(head + size) % array.length] = elem;
    size++;
    notifyAll();
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized E remove() {
    E elem = null;
    while (size == 0) {
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new UnexpectedException(e);
      }
    }

    elem = array[head];
    array[head] = null;
    head = (head + 1) % array.length;
    size--;
    notifyAll();
    return elem;
  }

}
```

And the one without a capacity limit which is where I need help (MyMBQueueU)

```java
public class MyMBQueueU<E> extends MBQueue<E> {

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * @param initialCapacity Initial queue capacity.
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code capacity <= 0}
   */
  public MyMBQueueU(int initialCapacity) {
    super(initialCapacity);
  }
  
  @Override
  public synchronized int capacity() {
    return UNBOUNDED;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void add(E elem) {
    if (size == array.length) {
      this.array = Arrays.copyOf(this.array, array.length * 2);
    }

    array[(head + size) % array.length] = elem;
    size++;
    notifyAll();
  }

}
```

By running tests with Cooperari on **MyMBQueueU** I get random NPE's on the ones where I have adding and removing at the same time with multiple threads. Sometimes it doesn't even throw NPE's, it just passes the tests.

Example test:

```java
BQueue<Integer> q = createBQueue(capacity);
    AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger b = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();
    CSystem.forkAndJoin(
        () -> { q.add(1); }, 
        () -> { q.add(10);},
        () -> { q.add(100);},
        () -> { a.set(q.remove()); },
        () -> { b.set(q.remove()); },
        () -> { c.set(q.remove()); }
        );
    assertEquals(0, q.size());
    assertEquals(111, a.get() + b.get() + c.get());
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this one because I have even tried a bunch of things, like using reentrant locks for example on the add() but I get the same behavior. I'm just kinda lost at this point

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pc.bqueue.BQueueTest.lambda$test3$18(BQueueTest.java:94)
    at org.cooperari.preemptive.NonCooperativeThreadRunner$NCThread.run(NonCooperativeThreadRunner.java:171)
```

BQueueTest.java:94 refers to

```
        () -> { a.set(q.remove()); },
==>     () -> { b.set(q.remove()); },
        () -> { c.set(q.remove()); }
```

Comment: Hey! Could you tell where the NPEs exactly occur please?

Comment: @akuzminykh My bad for not saying that. I get NPE's on b.set(q.remove()) for example in the test I mentioned

Comment: @akuzminykh The structure is using a circular array so the module division is needed to get the positions. I think it is correct since the MyMBQueue works fine on all tests all the time
Unfortunately the stack trace doesn't give much information beyond what I told you.
I updated the post with a stack trace

Answer (score 0):

When you grow your array you double the length thus either head % length or (head + size) % length will end up pointing in wrong half of your new array (with the exception of everything being correct if your head was exactly divisible by length * 2). You can fix this by moving misplaced elements to appropriate positions.

Imagine (e denoting empty element):

head = 10, size = 4, array = {2,3,0,1}

growing results in:

head = 10, size = 4, array = {2,3,0,1,e,e,e,e}

while correct one would be   {e,e,0,1,2,3,e,e}

similarly for:

head = 6, size = 4, array = {2,3,0,1}

growing results in:

head = 6, size = 4, array = {2,3,0,1,e,e,e,e}

while correct one would be  {2,3,e,e,e,e,0,1}